# BufferedInputStream isn't marking

Tags: java, inputstream

A BufferedInputStream that I have isn't marking correctly. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = "HelloWorld!".getBytes();
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
    bin.mark(3);
    while (true){
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int n = bin.read(buf);
        if (n == -1) break;
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(new String(buf, 0, n));
    }
}
```

This is outputting:

```
11
HelloWorld!
```

I want it to output

```
3
Hel
8
loWorld!
```

I also tried the code with just a pure ByteArrayInputStream as `bin`, and it didn't work either.

Comment: In your situation the `BufferedInputStream` is completely pointless and should be removed. The underlying `ByteArrayInputStream` is already completely buffered and supports any amount of mark/reset.

Comment: @EJP Why do people feel the need to comment on a seven-year-old question with "that's a bad example."

Comment: But I'll respond anyway. In the interest of keeping my MCVE similar to the source, I decided to keep the `BufferedInputStream` because the original code had a BufferedInputStream. I'm sorry I didn't optimize my short example code? "Completely pointless"? Well so is the whole program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `mark` does.

The purpose of `mark` is to cause the stream to remember its *current* position, so you can return to it later using `reset()`.  The argument isn't how many bytes will be read next -- it's how many bytes you'll be able to read afterward before the mark is considered invalid (ie: you won't be able to `reset()` back to it; you'll either get an exception or end up at the start of the stream instead).

See [the docs on InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) for details.  Readers' `mark` methods work quite similarly.

Comment: and make sure that `markSupported` returns true for whatever InputStream implementation you are using.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what mark() does. You need to re-read the documentation. Mark lets you go *backward* through the stream.